# how to add information in a tuple?

Tags: python

hi I'm new to programming and I have to do a language processing task with python. what I'm trying to do is that I have a list of nouns for example

```
nouns=['hotel','staff','pool']
```

and a text that need to be tagged based on whether each word in the text can be found in the noun list? for example

```
text=['the','hotel','is','really','nice','.']
```

if each element in the text can be found in noun list, then put yes, otherwise put no.the ideal output looks like this.

```
output=[('the','no'),('hotel','yes'),('is','no'),('really','no'),('nice','no'),('.','no')]
```

Comment: Why is `'hotel'` yes?

Comment: Presumably because it's in the list of nouns.

Comment: why hotel is yes?

Answer (score 3):

You want to be searching for a noun so better to make it a [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). A `list` would perform linear search.See [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set):

```
>>> nouns = {'hotel', 'room', 'staff', 'pool'}

>>> text = ['the', 'hotel', 'is', 'really', 'nice', '.']
>>> [(word, 'yes' if word in nouns else 'no')
...  for word in text]
[('the', 'no'),
 ('hotel', 'yes'),
 ('is', 'no'),
 ('really', 'no'),
 ('nice', 'no'),
 ('.', 'no')]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the performance difference between using `in` on  
a set/dict or a list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just forgot `hotel` in the `nouns` list:

**Script:**

```
nouns = {'room','staff','pool','hotel'}
text = ['the','hotel','is','really','nice','.']
out = [(word, 'yes' if word in nouns else 'no') for word in text]
print(out)
```

**Or the hacky way: even shorter:**

```
nouns = {'room','staff','pool','hotel'}
text = ['the','hotel','is','really','nice','.']
out = [(word, ['no','yes'][word in nouns]) for word in text]
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    ('the', 'no'), 
    ('hotel', 'yes'), 
    ('is', 'no'), 
    ('really', 'no'), 
    ('nice', 'no'), 
    ('.', 'no')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
nouns=['room','staff','pool']
text=['the','hotel','is','really','nice','.']
[(n, 'yes') if n in nouns else (n, 'no') for n in text]
```